# laravel echo server with laradock

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-echo, laradock

I'm trying to setup laravel echo server with docker and socket.io.

Backend seems to be working fine when I send event from laravel it shows up in laravel echo logs.

[image]

But when I try to connect from frontend it doesn't show anything in logs. From what I've gathered every connection should show up like this
[image]

But I get nothing.

My client code:

```
window.echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: 'localhost' + ':6001'
});

window.echo.channel('laravel_database_test')
    .listen('.Test', e => {
        console.log(e)
    })
```

When I open browser requests it keeps sending request to

```
http://localhost:6001/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NqPSDER
```

and response

```
96:0{"sid":"aMA7f9VU7IQwT1UcAADu","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":5000}2:40
```

But they are started right after new Echo(...) when I call window.echo.channel(..) no additional requests being sent.

**EDIT**

I noticed that ws is connected successfully
[image]

I also checked laravel echo API but not sure what it means

```
**apps/../status**
{"subscription_count":5,"uptime":394.2726654,"memory_usage":{"rss":75575296,"heapTotal":20889600,"heapUsed":19851984,"external":1030517,"arrayBuffers":87478}}

**apps/../channels**
{"channels":{}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that for whataever reason socket.io client doesn't work and needs to be downgraded to version 2.4.0.